# VOIP dialer in iOS

Tags: ios, voip

I want to create an iOS application which acts as a VOIP dialer.
I need to know does apple allow VOIP Dialing in iOS.? IF yes then what libraries should I use  and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course apple allow the voip application on Apple Store. there are hundreds of app on apple store like bria(counter path), vippi , Adore SIP client..............

Please follow the Below URL:

http://code.google.com/p/siphon/ that is using pjsip integration.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has allowed multiple VoIP apps in the app store. One option for building an app like this would be [Twilio Client which has an iOS SDK](http://www.twilio.com/api/client/sdk) currently in beta.

(I work at Twilio)

Comment: Is it possible to use Twilio Client as voip support library to develop a voip client under iOS without using Twilio Services?

Answer (score 0):

I want to create an iOS application which acts as a VOIP dialer. I need to know does apple allow VOIP Dialing in iOS.? IF yes then what libraries should I use and how?

Hello Dear,
yes, apple allows VOIP Dialing in iOS with swift and C both. as I was making R&D for same then I found the best way to implement VoIP in IOS and android both is PJSip. you can see [here.](http://www.pjsip.org/) and there are many of open source using this for that [see](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Projects_Using_PJSIP). and for IOS specially see [it](https://code.google.com/archive/p/siphon/).

Enjoy your code time:)